# Create Diagonal Matrix from column of a multi shape array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array like

`mat = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])`

which has shape (3,2). I want to create A new array with the shape (3,2,2) by taking the last axis of the array and create diagonal matrices out of it. I can do it with a for loop like

```
mat2 = np.zeros((3,2,2))
for i in np.arange(0,3):
    mat2[i] = np.diag(mat[i])
```

which yields the desired output

```
[[[1. 0.]
  [0. 1.]]

 [[2. 0.]
  [0. 2.]]

 [[3. 0.]
  [0. 3.]]]
```

But is there a way to do it in a direct vectorized (faster?!) version? In my real problem I have a large highly dimensional array of shape (...,n) and need to convert the last axis into a diagonal matrix with shape (...,n,n) in the end.

Comment: Is your concern performance?

Comment: Yes it is. So what what I am doing is flattening the whole array into shape (M,n) and running the abovementioned for loop but as M is huge it takes a while and I think that there must be a more efficient solution to the problem in terms of performance.

Comment: have you tried np.reshape?
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: How can reshape be used to create a new axis? I use reshape in combination with np.diag() by first reshaping my array (...,n) into (M,n) -> then diagonalize with a for loop running from 0...M and then reshaping it to the desired form.

Answer (score 3):

Here a possible implementation: use [np.diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html#numpy.diagonal) to take a view of the relevant diagonals and force the view to be writeable with `setflags`, and write to the view:

```py
expanded = np.zeros(mat.shape + mat.shape[-1:], dtype=mat.dtype)
diagonals = np.diagonal(expanded, axis1=-2, axis2=-1)
diagonals.setflags(write=True)

diagonals[:] = mat

expanded
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a great library called `numba` that allows to just in time compile python functions to get a speed comparable to C/Fortran when dealing with numpy arrays.
If you are at a point where you cannot express your problem vectorized this can save your day.

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def get_diag_mat(mat):
    mat2 = np.zeros((mat.shape[0], mat.shape[1], mat.shape[1]))
    for i in range(mat2.shape[0]):
        mat2[i] = np.diag(mat[i])
    return mat2
```

Even if you can vectorize your problem with numpy, you can sometimes save some memory, when you switch to "`jitted`" loops.

PS: The first execution of the function has an overhead because of compilation.

PPS: Note that you rarely want to use `np.arange`. Especially not for looping. python3's `range` is lazy and does not construct an array of integers in your memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the np.eye function and multiply.

```
>>> mat = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
>>> np.multiply(np.eye(2),mat[:,np.newaxis])
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  2.]],

       [[ 3.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  3.]]])
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest.

Comment: Clean, but seems inefficient to use a multiply when a copy will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [219]: m = mat.shape[-1]                                                                    
In [220]: mat2 = np.zeros(mat.shape+(m,),mat.dtype)                                            
In [221]: idx = np.arange(m)                                                                   
In [222]: mat2[...,idx,idx] = mat[...,idx]                                                     
In [223]: mat2                                                                                 
Out[223]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])
```

testing on a larger `mat`:

```
In [224]: mat = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])                                            
In [225]: m = mat.shape[-1]                                                                    
In [226]: mat2 = np.zeros(mat.shape+(m,),mat.dtype)                                            
In [227]: idx = np.arange(m)                                                                   
In [228]: mat2[...,idx,idx] = mat[...,idx]                                                     
In [230]: mat2                                                                                 
Out[230]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3]],

       [[2, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 4]],

       [[3, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 5]]])
```